# Server closes connection before replying

Tags: c, tcpclient, tcp

I'm following the MSDN lessons about TCP/IP client; my issue is that the server isn't replying and the connection closes  after I send the Headers.

```
const char *USR_PORT = "80";
#define BUFF_LEN 512
char recv_buf[BUFF_LEN];
const char HEADER_TO_SEND[] = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.microsoft.com\r\nUser-Agent: RequestHeaderC\r\n\r\n";
{...}
do {
    iRes = recv(ConnSocket, recv_buf, BUFF_LEN, 0);
    if (iRes > 0)
    {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iRes);
        for (i = 0; (i < iRes) && recv_buf[i] != '\0'; i++)
            printf("%c", recv_buf[i]);
    }
    else if (iRes == 0)
        printf("Connection closed by the server.\n");
    else printf("Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
} while (iRes > 0);
```

I'm almost sure the connection was fine as I sent with success the bytes.
I don't receive any byte at all.
  The other codes are almost the same as the ones in the tutorial, that's why I haven't posted them. If needed, I will

The server doesn't close the connection immediately if I remove this line:

```
shutdown(ConnSocket, SD_SEND);
```

But then I don't get any answer anyways, even if I add

```
Connection: close\r\n
```

in the headers

Full code:

```
const char *USR_PORT = "80";
#define BUFF_LEN 512
char USR_ADDR[] = "www.microsoft.com";
const char HEADER_TO_SEND[] = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.microsoft.com\r\nUser-Agent: RequestHeaderC\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

int main()
{
WSADATA wsaData;
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
{
    printf("Error: Wsastartup\n");
    exit(1);
}
int iRes;
addrinfo *result, *ptr, addr;
SecureZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.ai_family = AF_INET;
addr.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
addr.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
iRes = getaddrinfo(USR_ADDR, USR_PORT, &addr, &result);
if ( iRes != 0 )
{
    printf("Error: getaddrinfo");
    WSACleanup();
    exit(2);
}
SOCKET ConnSocket;
ptr = result;

ConnSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);
if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Error: socket: %ld \n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(3);
}
if (connect(ConnSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen) )
{
    closesocket(ConnSocket);
    ConnSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
}
if (ConnSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Invalid Socket\n");
    exit(4);
}

const char *send_buf = HEADER_TO_SEND;
char recv_buf[BUFF_LEN];
if ((iRes = send(ConnSocket, send_buf, strlen(send_buf) - 1, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error: send\n");
    closesocket(ConnSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(5);
}
int i;
for (i = 0; i < iRes; i++)
    printf("%c", send_buf[i]);
printf("Bytes sent: %d\n", iRes);


//if (shutdown(ConnSocket, SD_SEND) == SOCKET_ERROR)
//{
//  printf("Error: shutdown: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
//  closesocket(ConnSocket);
//  WSACleanup();
//  exit(6);
//}


//do {
    iRes = recv(ConnSocket, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf)-1, 0);
    if (iRes > 0)
    {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iRes);
        recv_buf[iRes] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < iRes; i++)
            printf("%c", recv_buf[i]);
    }
    else if (iRes == 0)
        printf("Connection closed by the server.\n");
    else printf("Error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
//} while (iRes > 0);

getchar();
getchar();
closesocket(ConnSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Naturally if you call shutdown on the socket the server will drop the connection and you will not be able to receive anything. What are you expecting the server to send you in response to your sent buffer? Who wrote that server, was it you? How do you know it works ok?

Comment: I've also tried without the shutdown(), but SD_SEND should tell I won't send anything more but not to close the connection, so that it can wait for bytes from the server.
It waits for the server to send back a header, like the one I sent to it. (the server's www.microsoft.com, tried with google.com too)

Comment: Your question is more about http than TCP isn't it? You could download Wireshark and see what packets are sent between your computer and the server. It should help you understand whether you're not sending the right packet or not receiving correctly

Comment: My packets are sent correctly, and the destination IP matches www.microsoft.com; anyways, I don't get any response

Comment: Is that what you saw with a network sniffer? No response at all?

Comment: It seems so to me. I have only seen other apps' packets, but the one I was looking for wasn't there. I may have another look if I can't fix this.